# Swift Package Manager platform-specific resources: iOS xibs do not support target device type 'mac'

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I am building a library using Swift Package Manager. I have added a XIB file to define the layout of a custom `UICollectionViewCell`. My package will not compile in Xcode, because the XIB file is specific to iOS. If I create a macOS XIB, then the opposite error occurs. This seems to be because:

1. Libraries built by Swift Package Manager will always be cross-platform, and so I can't build an "iOS-only" package.
2. Code can use mechanisms like `#if os(iOS)` to handle platform-specific code.
3. `resources: [ .process("resource.name") ]` has no `BuildSettingCondition` to tell it to include a specific XIB file only when building for iOS.
4. `.xib` is handled automatically by Xcode, without being declared in `Package.swift` because it's obvious that they're resource files and so [Xcode handles them automatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/bundling_resources_with_a_swift_package).
5. `xcodebuild` doesn't seem to have rules which separate the two different `.xib` files for platform-specific processing.

What am I missing? How can I ensure that iOS-specific resources are not forced to be included in the final package?

Comment: Try changing the run target to an ios device like iPhone 12 .

Comment: It's really, really unfortunate that there is no answer to this yet. If the build process can detect that it's an iOS XIB, it should also be able to automatically exclude it, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Any updates to this?

Answer (score 1):

Under the build settings change the target from what ever the value is, to "Any iOS Type"

[image]